Query all documents in Azure CosmosDB for NoSQL
I am trying to get all documents in a collection in CosmosDB for NoSQL in Azure using Golang but I get null value when trying to do a HTTP GET call to the database.
When I try to pass a specific value from the document which is the partitionkey value in the NewPartitionKeyFromString method. But I need to fetch all the records present in that container similar to fetchAll records for other relational databases.
func GetAssets(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    query := "SELECT * FROM c"
    containerClient, err := getContainerClient(database, container)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to get container client", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    queryOptions := &azcosmos.QueryOptions{}
    partitionKeyValue := azcosmos.NewPartitionKeyString("assetType")
    pager := containerClient.NewQueryItemsPager(query, partitionKeyValue, queryOptions)

    var assets []models.Asset
    for pager.More() {
        page, err := pager.NextPage(context.TODO())

        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Failed to execute query: %v", err)
            http.Error(w, "Failed to execute query", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        // Check if items exist in the page
        if len(page.Items) == 0 {
            log.Println("No items found in this page.")
            continue // Skip to the next page if no items found
        }

        for _, item := range page.Items {
            var asset models.Asset // Declare asset as the defined struct
            if err := json.Unmarshal(item, &asset); err != nil {
                log.Printf("Failed to unmarshal item: %v", err)
                http.Error(w, "Failed to unmarshal item", http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }
            assets = append(assets, asset)
        }
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(assets); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to encode response: %v", err)
        http.Error(w, "Failed to encode response", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

}

Please Note: I have recently started learning golang. Any type of suggestions are welcomed

Where exactly are you getting the nil (null) ?

What's the path of your partition key? Is it /assetType? If so, you need to pass the value as partitionKeyValue, not the path.

I am getting the data as null. And path of my partition key is /assetType. If its the value to be passed it would filter based on that value. I need to fetch all records for a general select all query over database

@MatiasQuaranta : I have 2 records manually entered in the db but the result is still null that's my concern.

Secondly @DavidMakogon i need to fetch all records as mentioned for select all query

Ok, so you're passing "assetType" as the parameter. You either need to pass the value, or pass nothing for partition key value and enable cross-partition query. You can't just pass the path of the partition key, and you can't just set the value to null.

Based on the comments,  partitionKeyValue := azcosmos.NewPartitionKeyString("assetType") should be the value of the property.
For example, if your documents look like:
{
  "id": "the id",
  "assetType": "car"
}

Then it should be  partitionKeyValue := azcosmos.NewPartitionKeyString("car")
The Go SDK does not support cross-partition queries at this time, so you can only query within a logical partition value. You cannot get all the documents for all the partitions.

Thanks @MatiasQuaranta for sharing details for better understanding. And also for confirming that Go isnt capable of performing cross partition queries.

@akash24 here is the workitem tracking that feature https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/23563

Thanks for sharing this @MatiasQuaranta
